# Hashing for WCF Service API

Tags: c#, wcf, hash, wcf-security

We are getting ready to expose a large amount of WCF services over an API in which we want all services to have common authentication/authorization.

We were thinking of requiring a hashed value (possibly username and password) on each of the requests, but I am not sure if this is the best practice way, or even a correct way. Additionally, if it isn't, then what is? If it is, then what hashing algorithm would be able to be supported for a language independent algorithm. Our goal is to not restrict to any specific language.

Comment: I think you are mixing encryption and hashing, if you really need security hashing alone wont do it, you will need encryption as well, either symmetric or asymmetric encryption. If you can be more specific I might be able to help.

We are currently implementing a large project where we use JWS (signed JWT) as part of the HTTPS protocol along with SOAP as the body.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with one of my startups and we further wanted to avoid SSL so we decided to encrypt all of our traffic and provide a private key to our clients.  That said, we found out the hard way that cross platform encryption is HARD.  In fact, we ended up discovering that the only decent option was by a company called Chilkat (http://www.chilkatsoft.com/).

The other options we went through all had issues when going between Windows and non-Windows environments.  Chilkat worked much better but be careful of the encryption algorithms you use and note that you need to change some of their settings if you want UTF-8 over ASCII.

We also, eventually, automated the private key part by providing a service that asked for a company name, email address and contact name and then we used those to auto-generate and email user-level private keys to clients.  They then used that to encrypt on their end using a .NET or Java library we provided.